# for nothing but editing and navigating text as quickly as possible: is there any reason to prefer vim over vim emulations in emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs

EDIT:
1. Let's not make this a general vim/emacs debate. I know some people prefer standard emacs, I want a modal input system.
2. When I say Vim emulation, I mean something like http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil or http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Vimpulse

I edit a lot of text (as in notes, mail etc.), I want to do it as quickly as possible. It seems like a good idea to learn how to use something more complicated than text edit. **Is there any significant difference between the potential speed of an experienced user of either vim or vim emulation X in emacs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you pick one of them (VIM/emacs), mixing them (with a plugin) isn't something that great since I wouldn't expect all the functionality to be there.

Besides that, I don't see any reason why you would need such a thing. VIM or Emacs are pretty fast without one emulating the other, so you wouldn't need such a plugin.

If you really want to be extra fast, I know VIM has a really nice plugin called [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526) (watch a quick video of it in action from [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-easymotion/)).

Edit: @Daimrod said Emacs has a similar plugin called [ace-jump-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AceJump)

Comment: But of course there is something similar to EasyMotion in Emacs called [ace-jump-mode](https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode/wiki/Home/53d6e134e4af7eab191a522271c4c66a5dbb7ccc)

Comment: Of course, (x)emacs is all about doing things quickly anyway - that is the point of all of the chording combinations.

Comment: maybe vim emulation is the wrong word, I meant something like http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil or http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Vimpulse

Comment: That doesn't change the significance of the question / answer in my opinion. My answer would be the same.

Comment: I see, wasn't sure about that

Comment: So don't worry, if you pick Vim / Emacs is good. Both of them are really great, but from what I've surfed the web there are a lot more resources (tutorials + videos) on VIM: nettuts & peepcode both have great tutorials (which I saw when first learning Vim).

Comment: @TorThommesen: Vim emulation is usally good when you already know Vim and you want to use Emacs, but I think that trying to learn both a the same time is suicidal. I used to use Vim, then I've switched to Emacs + Vimpulse but now I only use Emacs.

Comment: @Daimrod is perfectly right. That would be really messy and you would have a really hard time understanding which comes from where.

Answer (score 1):

Go for Emacs. You'll have the VIM keys if you prefer that and you'll also have the power of Emacs at your disposal.